¿Saben cuál es la mejor forma de realizar un lector de código QR en vue js 3.0?
Hola comunidad actualmente estoy presentando un problema con la visualizacion de un codigo QR estoy haciendo uso del componete ensamblado zxing_reader.wasm, estoy usando vue js 3.0
async function onDetect (codigosdetectados) {
  qrResult.value = detectedCodes.map((code) => code.rawValue);
  emit("archivo", result.value);
  paused.value = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    paused.value = false;
  }, 500);
}

el problema es que no lee los codigos pero tampoco manda error

Y todo el resto del codigo para reproducir tu problema? la pagina de ejemplo tiene bastantes cosas.. como esta eso insertado en tus componentes?

ya estoy verificando y creo es por una restriccion en las politicas de seguridad vue-qrcode-reader.js:536
Refused to connect to 'https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/zxing-wasm@1.1.3/dist/reader/zxing_reader.wasm' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

imagino que debes tener los permisos de camara para poder usarlo, verifica eso
